# mongoDB - Get data from one collection and save to another collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am making a node.js website, and I recently added a dependent dropdown for selecting location. The HTML and JS are here in my previous question: [Country state city select in nodejs using mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64943265/country-state-city-select-in-nodejs-using-mongodb).

I have the country, state, and city's "id" key's value as the value in the dynamically generated HTML on the page and I have been able to save the ids to MongoDB.

I am using the form itself to show profile data to the user to update anything without any extra clicks. To show the user data, I had already created a function called on page load that gets the user's object from DB and populates the page with data by setting innerHTML for divs and ps on page .value attributes for form fields. So I need to save the required data in the user's document in DB.

It is also better to store the data in the user document instead of aggregating each time a user loads a page. I saved the data to the user document. As of now, I'm able to get the "id"s for the country, state, and city from the form I built using the help from the previous question I linked above. Now I need to query the `"states_cities"` collection using the ids I get from the form and save the location's name and value so that I can use them to update the form on page load.

Here's my attempt with the profileUpdate route in server.js file:

```js
        app.post("/profileUpdate", function (request, result) {

            var accessToken = request.fields.accessToken;
            var name = request.fields.name;
            var dob = request.fields.dob;
            var gender = request.fields.gender;
            var country = parseInt(request.fields.country, 10);
            var state = parseInt(request.fields.state, 10);
            var city = parseInt(request.fields.city, 10);
            var aboutMe = request.fields.aboutMe;

            database.collection("users").findOne({
                "accessToken": accessToken
            }, function (error, user) {
                if (user == null) {
                    result.json({
                        "status": "error",
                        "message": "User has been logged out. Please login again."
                    });
                } else {
                    database.collection("states_cities").findOne({
                        "id": state
                    }, function(error, data){
                        state = {"name": data.name,
                                "id": data.id}
                    });
                    database.collection("states_cities").findOne({
                        "cities.id": city
                    }, function(error, data){
                        city = {"name": data.cities.$.name,
                                "id": data.cities.$.id}
                    });

                    database.collection("users").updateOne({
                        "accessToken": accessToken
                    }, {
                        $set: {
                            "name": name,
                            "dob": dob,
                            "country": country,
                            "state": state,
                            "city": city,
                            "gender": gender,
                            "aboutMe": aboutMe,
                        }
                    }, function (error, data) {
                        result.json({
                            "status": "success"
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Please help

Please refer to my last question linked at the top for more details regarding other code and DB schema parts.

Comment: your `updateOne` is outside of the finds callback, so it'll be called before getting your data

Comment: I made necessary changes, now I'm getting state data and I'm able to console.log(state) in cmd. But the city part isn't working. The error I'm getting is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined". The type of "id" in mongodb is Int32 and I'm parsing the string exactly like it works for state but isn't working for city!! What to do

Comment: you have the callback problem twice in your code, for state and city

Comment: Yes, I had already noticed that, so I put the update inside city callback and city find inside state callback. It didn't work so I fetched the option text and saved it instead. It works for me now but i'd still like to make it work with mongo update